# RemoveFrom and then delete()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, has-many

I have strange problem with deleting many objects from a hasMany association and then deleting the object itself.

I have domain class website and user (I don't have a 'belongsTo' relation):

```
class User {
}
class Website {
    static hasMany = [websiteUsers : User]
}
```

and this method:

```
void deleteUserFromWebsite(User user,Website website){
    log.debug "-----> deleteUserFromWebsite()"
    println website.websiteUsers
    website.removeFromWebsiteUsers(user)
    println website.websiteUsers
    user.delete(flush:true)
    log.debug "deleteUserFromWebsite ----->"
}
```

**When I call this method once, everything is okay, but when I want make mass action at the same time in one request** (delete 2 or more users) I have errors from hibernate:

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

It happens because hibernate doesn't remove the user from the association in the website.

Log from two method calls with different users:

```
2013-08-19 16:49:56,769 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG website.WebsiteService  - -----> deleteUserFromWebsite)
[com.**.security.User : 17, com.**.security.User : 3, com.**.security.User : 12, com.**.security.User : 21, com.**.security.User : 16]
[com.**.security.User : 17, com.**.security.User : 3, com.**.security.User : 21, com.**.security.User : 16]
2013-08-19 16:49:56,777 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG website.WebsiteService  - deleteUserFromWebsite ----->
[com.**.security.User : 17, com.**.security.User : 3, com.**.security.User : 21, com.**.security.User : 16]
2013-08-19 16:49:56,811 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ObjectDeletedException occurred when processing request: [POST] /**/**/** - parameters:
users: 12,16
websiteId: mol24o
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.**.security.User#16]. Stacktrace follows:
```

In first call hibernate removes the user from the association (userId: 12), but the second time, the user with id 16 wasn't delete from the has many and then when I want to delete the object, hibernate of course throws an exception.

Is there any way to make hibernate flush his cache and update websiteUsers?

Comment: can you add the code where you're doing the mass delete

Comment: Has this been resolved yet?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the "mass action"? The error indicates that you're using (or have a reference) to the user that you're trying to delete.

For example if you're cycling through the websiteUsers collection as you're deleting than that will cause this error.

Take a look at [GORM Gotchas](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) for a very good explanation of this.